# How much of a performance hit is $($('selector'))?

Tags: jquery, performance

I'm working on an application which currently has something like this:

```
var selector = '.selector';
$(selector).methodA();
$(selector).methodB();
//.....
$(selector).methodZ();
```

To increase performance I'm going to change `selector` to a jQuery object such as:

```
var selector = $('.selector');
selector.methodA();
selector.methodB();
//.....
selector.methodZ();
```

However as this is a very large application this will have to be changed in stages, meaning that until its fully complete there will be code such as:

```
var selector = $('.selector');
selector.methodA();
$(selector).methodB();
//.....
$(selector).methodZ();
```

Would this last code snippet be better performance wise than my first code snippet?

My guess is that as the object is already a jQuery object, any implementation will be bypassed and simply output the inputted object, but I want to make sure for certain.

Or would it be best to ensure only my 2nd code snippet goes live?

Comment: Have you setup a jsperf ?

Comment: There is a (fairly minor, but entirely unnecessary) performance-hit, but you can see this for yourself at [JS Perf](http://jsperf).

Comment: This is selector caching - browsers are constantly evolving how they handle this, as @Ravi suggested, creating a jsperf would reveal some interesting results about how browsers currently handle caching.

Comment: @Ravi Thanks I wasn't aware of this performance tool for JS. I've posted an answer with the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@Ravi's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527584/how-much-of-a-performance-hit-is-selector/15528313#comment21995172_15527584) I've used jsPerf to test the performance and heres the results:

[image]
http://jsperf.com/nested-jquery-testing

Therefore the 3rd test is actually quicker than the 1st.

Comment: Based on your results, I would guess that under-the-hood, JQuery is checking if the object is already a JQuery object and if so returning it (test C), rather than having to create a new JQuery object each call (test A)

Comment: Also, I think your TEST C is wrong, should all 3 click lines use `$(selector)`?

Comment: @musefan Thats right: `My guess is that as the object is already a jQuery object, any implementation will be bypassed and simply output the inputted object, but I want to make sure for certain.`. I just wanted proof that this would actually be better for performance rather than making assumptions.

Comment: @musefan TEST C deliberately has a mixture to show a real-life example of where there may be some which have been changed, and some which are still `$(selector)`. See my question: `However as this is a very large application this will have to be changed in stages, meaning that until its fully complete there will be code such as:` (followed by a code snippet similar to Test C)

Comment: yeah... seems I should have read more of your question. Good to have the confirmation anyway. I have learned a little more - not enough to ask my boss for a payrise though... maybe I'll learn something special  enough for that tomorrow :(